# dequeue function in wordpress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am trying to dequeue some scripts from non-relevant pages in wordpress. It is working fine with some (like contact-form-7) but not with other plugins. Is there any reasons these .js and .css files are still being loaded, despite being dequeued?

Code below is loaded via  functions.php in child-theme. Relevant plugin is [woo-variation-swatches](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variation-swatches/).

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_swatches_script_conditional_loading' );

function custom_swatches_script_conditional_loading(){
   //  Edit page IDs here
   if(! is_page(39341) )      
   {        
      wp_dequeue_style('woo-variation-swatches');  // Dequeue CSS file.
      wp_dequeue_style('woo-variation-swatches-theme-override');  // Dequeue CSS file.      
      wp_dequeue_style('woo-variation-swatches-tooltip');  // Dequeue CSS file.
      wp_dequeue_script('woo-variation-swatches'); // Dequeue JS Script file.
   }
}
```

Comment: you should include your `add_action` in the question

Comment: In your add_action call, you can also set a priority, it might has less-priority than the other plugins (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)

Comment: @HowardE added, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to either hook it after `wp_enqueue_scripts` like `wp_print_styles` or simply try setting the priority of your `add_action`.

Looking at the plugin source code.  It enqueue's the scripts with priority 15.

woo-variation-swatches.php line 103.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ), 15 );
```

So really, anything priority higher than 15 should dequeue it like this :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_swatches_script_conditional_loading', 99 );
```